# Running Unit Test on ASP.Net MVC5 with DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I currently using Unit Testing on my projects but it seems I have trouble on getting the data on my site DBContext, I assume that I need to run the web project then run the test but I dont think Visual Studio permits that.

So I tried opening 2 instances of Visual Studio but it still did not work.

This is my code:

```
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsDbNull()
    { 
        var dblist = db.StudentInformation.ToList(); 
        Assert.IsNotNull(dblist);
    }
```

A simple assert to check if the project can read my database, I tried debuging and dblist doesn't have any items on it.

I saw some codes that uses fake database by putting it as CSV but as much I dont want to go that method since I want to test the  real data itself.

I also saw "Run Tests" on GitHub but it only supports VS 2012

Comment: Database configuration is typically done with configuration (connection strings in .config files) - I'd start looking there. The DbContext ran in the test project may very well be pointing to a different database

Comment: actually it just reference on it, since its a Unit Test there is no .config

Comment: so make one? I don't have much EF experience, but I do know that if you've got a configuration dependency in a test project, you'll need that configuration in there *somehow*

Comment: Are you sure you know what Unit Test is? If I make the configuration in the test project then I will need to replicate the database which is pointless because its a Unit Test. Its purpose is just to test the main project not to have its own configurations

Comment: Unit testing implies you're testing the smallest useful measurable code, which "the real data" using an external database definitely doesn't fit it. Regardless of whether we're calling it unit testing, integration testing, or following Nyan cat, I still think you would need configuration available to the test project to connect to a database.

Comment: Bottom line of what I'm saying - you need connection strings (or more generally, configuration) for testing the real data with an integration test, or mocking out the database connectivity objects, like you describe with fake CSV database.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what your doing here in my question, I ask a simple question about Unit Testing in Asp.Net yet you have derailed my question. You speak so much of the configuration yet I don't think you have tried Unit Testing in MVC 5.There is no need for connection string since I am referencing the main project, the main project has the connection string. Cant you even understand that simple logic.

Comment: The bottom line of what I'm saying, stop suggesting things you don't know. Its obvious I am referencing my DbContext as you can see in the code -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting aside discussions about what constitutes a unit test, as has been suggested by @jdphenix in the comments, your problem is likely to be a configuration issue.  The main evidence for this comes from your statement:

> I tried debuging and dblist doesn't have any items on it.

If your test code had failed to connect to *a* database, you would get an exception when attempting to read the contents from it rather than an empty list, which is what you are reporting.

In response to your comment:

> If I make the configuration in the test project then I will need to replicate the database which is pointless because its a Unit Test. Its purpose is just to test the main project not to have its own configurations

When using entity framework, if you don't supply it with configuration information, it will derive a connection string based on the namespace and class name of the context you are using to connect with the database (I believe it will also assume you want to use SQLEXPRESS as the provider, although that may be version dependant).  If you don't provide configuration information in your unit-test project, this is what the entity framework will do.  If you don't have any configuration in your application then the two will match, and everything will point at the same database.

In most real world applications however, your application will have some kind of connection information in it.  This will either be because you want a sensible database name, or you need to be able to control the machine that the database is on, or you need to use a different provider.  If this is the case then you need to replicate the connection string into your test project. Note, duplicating the connection string does not "replicate the database", it simply creates another pointer to the database.

It's also worth noting that if there is a mismatch in the test project, EF will try to create a new database with it's defaults if one doesn't already exist.

A simple way to check if it is a configuration issue is to debug your test and real code and compare the values of:

```
(((System.Data.Entity.DbContext)(db)).Database.Connection).ConnectionString
```

Where `db` is the instantiated name of your database context (note you'll have to execute a line like `db.StudentInformation.ToList()` before it is populated.

As you appear to be using the MS test framework, any configuration you need to be available for testing should be placed in an App.config file in the project (which may already have been added if you used nuget to reference the entity framework) to make it available (note, this varies with different testing frameworks and may also be different if you're using a non-standard test runner).